# AWS secretsmanager, lambda, access denied even with admin permissions

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, permissions, secretsmanager

I am stuck configuring my AWS Lambda to access a secret. I have done it many times, all the existing resources works properly, but now a new one does not want to.

Stack:
I have a secret in secretsmanager and a lambda (in vpc)

What I want: read the secret from lambda.

Role of the lambda has the following policy:

```
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "secretsmanager:GetSecretValue"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxx:secret:xxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

But even if I give **full admin permission** for this role, I am not allowed to read the secret from lambda. I get the following error message:

```
User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/xxxxxxx/yyyyyyyy is not authorized to perform: secretsmanager:GetSecretValue on resource: arn:aws:secretsmanager:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxx:secret:xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I have other lambdas that work, but it is a bit terrifying that re-deploying my cloudformation stack could break the whole application due to this.

I assume there was some change at AWS side, existing resources got changed to be compatible, but now I am not able to access any new or already existing secrets, even if I can see at the lambda configuration that I have permission.

Does anyone have any idea what is missing? Thanks!

Comment: Can you test the lambda role using IAM Policy Simulator to discard any issues with the permissions? https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/home/index.jsp?#

Comment: Yes, I did that one too, everything was right. I could resolve this, the service endpoint policy was too restrictive in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Turned out that I missed one place to check. When I dig deeper, I found that this whole thing happens only when the Lambda is tied to a VPC, but removing the VPC config made it work.

For me the missing piece was the endpoint policy for the secretsmanager (that allows me to access secretsmanager from VPC)